# How to calculate decision boundary from support vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I want to obtain decision boundary of SVM using OpenCV 2.4.11, [but it seems that it's not returning it explicitly, but only support vectors](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-get-support-vector).

How we can calculate decision boundary from support vectors?

**Update:**

Anyway seems via opencv interface I can't get lagrange multiplier $\alpha_i$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A binary SVM tries to separate subjects belonging to one of two classes based on some features, the class will be denoted as $y_i \in \{-1,+1\}$ and the features as $x_i$, note the $y_i$ is a single number while $x_i$ is a vector.  The index $i$ identifies the subject.

The SVM solves a quadratic programming problem and finds, for each subject  a lagrange multiplier $\alpha_i$, many of the $\alpha$'s are zero. Note that the $\alpha_i$ are numbers, so for each subject $i$ you have a **number** $y_i$, a feature **vector** $x_i$ and a lagrange multiplier $\alpha_i$ (a **number**).

You have also choosen a kernel $K(x,y)$ ($x$ and $y$ are **vectors**) for which you know the functional form and you have choosen a capacity parameter $C$.

The $x_i$ for which the corresponding $\alpha_i$ are non-zero are the support vectors.

To compute your decision boundary, I refer to [this article](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67119/svmtutorial.pdf). Formula (61) from the mentioned article learns that the decision boundary has the equation $f(x)=0$, where $f(x)=\sum_i \alpha_i y_i K(x_i, x) + b$ and as the $\alpha_i$ are only non-zero for the support vectors, this becomes (SV is the set of support vectors): $f(x)=\sum_{i \in SV} \alpha_i y_i K(s_i, x) + b$ (where I changed $x_i$ to $s_i$ as in formula (61) of the article, to indicate that only support vectors appear).

As you know all the support vectors, you know the (non-zero) $\alpha_i$, the corresponding (number) $y_i$ and the vectors $s_i$, you can compute this $f(x)$ if you know your kernel $K$ and the constant $b$.

**So we still have to find $b$**: The equations (55) and (56) of the article I referred to, learn that for an arbitrary $\alpha_i$ with $0 < \alpha_i < C$ (C is a parameter of your SVM) it holds that $y_i ( x_i \cdot w + b) = 1$ where $w$ is given by equation (46) of the article. So $b = \frac{1}{y_i} - x_i \cdot w=\frac{1}{y_i} - \sum_{k \in SV} \alpha_k y_k K(x_i, s_k)$.  (the '$\cdot$' is the inner product that will later be replaced by the kernel, see article that I referred to).

The latter holds for any of the $\alpha_i, 0 < \alpha_i < C$, so if you **choose one such** an $\alpha_i$ that is smaller than $C$ and positive , then you can compute $b$ from the corresponding observation: take an $m$ for which $0 < \alpha_m < C$, with this $m$ there corresponds an $x_m$ and an $y_m$. On the other hand you know all the support vectors $s_k$ (which are the vectors $x_k$ whith non-zero $\alpha_k$ see above) with their corresponding $y_k$ and $\alpha_k$. With all these you can compute $f(x)$ and $f(x)=0$ identifies the decision boundary, the sign of $f(x)$ determines the class.

So to summarise:

1. Take the subjects $k$ that correspond to the support vectors, i.e. for which the Lagrange multiplier $\alpha_k$ is not zero, for each such subject you have the Lagrange multiplier $\alpha_k$, the class $y_k \in \{-1,+1\}$, and the feature vector $x_k$ (denoted as $s_k$ to make it clear that it are support vectors);
2. Take one subject for which the Lagrange multiplier is strictly smaller than $C$, and strictly positive, assume this is object $m$ and use it to compute $b$ as $b =\frac{1}{y_m} - \sum_{k \in SV} \alpha_k y_k K(x_m, s_k)$;
3. The equation that identifies the decision boundary is $f(x)=0$ where $f(x)=\sum_{k \in SV} \alpha_k y_k K(s_k, x) + b$

Comment: Great answer! "margin" is decision boundary?  "inproduct" is inner product?

Comment: @mrgloom: you are right (+1), I will edit the text accordingly

Comment: @mrgloom: what do you think about this ? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168051/what-is-the-relationship-between-a-kernel-and-projection-to-a-higher-dimensional/168082#168082